# elasticsearch to return searched query

Tags: jquery, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

how is it going? 
I am using Elasticsearch with Haystack, and I want to find in a database a queried term inside of the documents. 
For exemple in database 'document' I have five documents files about agriculture. 
I want to find how many times, the word 'plant' is used, and where. 
so in the search query, when I enter **tree** I want the results to be

doc 1: ...plant their seeds of this **tree** during rainy seasons so that ... 
doc 1: ... the birds smell the flower of the **tree** they fly towards it...
doc 5: ... Orange is an evergreen **tree** (citrus sp.) native to India and Southern...

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, do you want the highlighting of tree or do you want counts for the term plant. It is not really clear what your question is. At least not to me.

Comment: 1. I want to read/print the line where the searched term is found, and 2. I want to count them. bold is used to differentiate the term from the rest of the text.